# Connecting to AWS RDS : Cannot resolve host

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, connection, rds

I am trying to connect me MySQL client to my amazon RDS.

For the purposes of testing I have allowed connections from anywhere 
in the security group and the instance is accessible from public internet. I am connecting to the endpoint as stated in
the documentation.

However my connection is failing with a 'cannot resolve host' error.
I have read through multiple docs but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. If the problem was a local firewall than the host would still resolve so I doubt it is that.

Has anyone had trouble with this?

Comment: Check the DNS at a site like https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A (enter the rds hostname and click 'search').  The hostname should return the same IP address from all the test locations shown.  If it works, you have a local issue blocking DNS resolution.  If not, you've copied the hostname incorrectly or there's a problem with RDS... but this would not be an issue with your RDS configuration.  Please advise what you find.

Comment: try to connect with ip address. if that works it is certainly an issue with dns.